# individually evaluating points in an array

Tags: matlab

I want to sort an array of numbers based on how large they are.

I want to run a loop using the values of an array so that it iterates each value individually. I will try to get it into somekind of psuedo code. I havent programmed in 3 years.

```
PL=(3,5,7,9,10);
EL=(3,2,2,2,1);

n=input;
x=array;
gp=2.5*(1:n)

% I want this to run for each value of PL seperately
for each PL_i in PL

    x=(EL(1,1) < gp <= PL); 
    % ...and then the vector x subtracted from each value of EL 
    gp2=(x-(EL);
    % ...and then put those values from gp2 back into an array 

end
```

Thanks for helping anyone I have worked on this program many hours. This step would greatly aid the entire project.

I can accomplish this using multiple if loops....

```
g=(gp(gp>0));
gp1=(gp(gp<=EL(1,1)));
if x1>=2
x=(gp((EL(2,1)<gp)));
pp=(gp(gp<=PL(2,1)));
gp2=[x,pp];
gpp2=(x-(EL(2,1)));
lpap=([gp1,gpp2]);
end
if x1>=3
x=(gp((EL(3,1)<gp)));
pp=(gp(gp<=PL(3,1)));
gp2=[x,pp];
gpp3=(x-(EL(3,1)));
lpap=([gp1,gpp2,gpp3]);
end
```

Comment: I'm confused by your explanation. Could you maybe just write it out in pseudo-code?

Comment: `gp` is an array, and `PL` is an array. What should `x` be?

Comment: x should also be an array. Is there any other information that isnt complete here?

Comment: This question, as it is stated, doesn't make sense. You can loop over the contents of PL, but you can't make the comparison `x=(EL(1,1) < gp <= PL_i);   `... `EL(1,1)` and `PL_i` are single values, but `gp` is a vector! What output are you expecting from that? Also, is the `gp2=(x-(EL))` line supposed to be vector subtraction or a single variable being subtracted from each component of the vector?

Comment: `x=(EL(1,1)< gp <=PL)` means that x takes on the values of `gp` that are between `EL(1)` and `PL`, or is it a logical array with ones wherever `gp` is between `EL(1)` and `PL`, and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Also, should there be one array `gp2` for each element in `PL` and `EL`?

Comment: @jonas x takes on the values of gp that are between EL(1,1) and PL  but I want that operation to repeat for each vector in PL     Also  yes there should be a gp2 array for each element in EL.    @eykanal the line gp2=x-EL should be a vector subtracted by a value. with the value being based off values in a vector. So the vector x should be subtracted by each point in EL separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I got it, I ended up changing how I wrote the program.

```
%Number of nodes and elements are entered.
NN=input('Enter the number of elements: ');
if NN <0;
    reply = 'Please enter more than 0 for the number of elements: ';
    NN=input('Number of Elements?:');
end
% prompt for length of elements also define the global length and total
% length 
for  x1=1:NN;
    EL(x1)=input(['Enter the length of element ', num2str(x1) ': ']);
    PL(x1)=tlength;
    tlength=tlength+EL(x1);
    PL(NN+1)=tlength;
end
%Enter the number of output points
npoints=input('Enter the number of desired output points: ' );
%Establish what order the elements are.
Order=input('Enter the order of the elements (1, 2, 3): ');
%Determine the spacing of the points
spacepoints=tlength/(npoints);
%Determine the global coordinate of the points
gp=(1:spacepoints:PL(NN));
%Get the local coordinates of the points
for c=1:1:npoints;
    for i=1:1:NN;
        if ((c-1)*spacepoints)<=PL(i+1) && ((c-1)*spacepoints)>=PL(i);
            local(c)=((c)*spacepoints)-PL(i); 

        end
        if ((c-1)*spacepoints)>=PL(NN);
            local(c)=((c)*spacepoints)-PL(NN);
            element(i)=NN;
        end

    end
end
%Get the natural coordinates from the local coordinates
for c=1:1:npoints;
    for i=1:1:NN;
        if ((c-1)*spacepoints)<PL(i+1) && ((c)*spacepoints)>PL(i);
            nc(c)=((2*local(c))/EL(i))-1;
        end
        if ((c-1)*spacepoints)>PL(NN);
            nc(c)=((2*local(c))/EL(NN))-1;
        end
    end
end
%Input for the nodal values
 for i=1:1:((Order*NN)+1)

  values(i)=input(['Enter the nodal value' num2str(i) ': ']);

 end
%To find the value for linear
if Order==1
  for i=1:1:NN;
      for c=1:1:npoints;
          if ((c-1)*spacepoints)<=PL(i+1) && ((c)*spacepoints)>=PL(i);
              si(c)=1/2*(1-nc(c));
              sj(c)=1/2*(1+nc(c));
              V(c)=si(c)*values(i)+sj(c)*values(i+1);
          end
          if ((c-1)*spacepoints)>=PL(NN);
              si(c)=1/2*(1-nc(c));
              sj(c)=1/2*(1+nc(c));
              V(c)=si(c)*values(i)+sj(c)*values(i+1);
          end
      end
  end
end    
%To find the value for a quadratic
if Order==2;
    for i=1:1:NN;
     for c=1:1:npoints;
     if ((c-1)*spacepoints)<PL(i+1) && ((c)*spacepoints)>PL(i);
     si(c)=(-1/2)*nc(c)*(1-nc(c));
     sk(c)=(1/2)*nc(c)*(1+nc(c));
     sj(c)=(1-nc(c))*(1+nc(c));
     V(c)=si(c)*values(2*i-1)+sj(c)*values(2*i)+sk(c)*values(2*i+1)
     end
     if ((c-1)*spacepoints)>PL(NN);
     si(c)=(-1/2)*nc(c)*(1-nc(c));
     sk(c)=(1/2)*nc(c)*(1+nc(c));
     sj(c)=(1-nc(c))*(1+nc(c));
     V(c)=si(c)*values(i*2-1)+sj(c)*values(i*2)+sk(c)*values((i*2)+1);
     end
     end 
    end
end
```